# Push back start date

Tags: professionalism, job-search, hiring-process, human-resources

I am a foreigner in country X, currently serving notice at a company A and recently got a job offer from company B. My work permit will be cancelled when I resign and I can stay at most 4 weeks in country X without work permit. So I need to be sure that I get a new work permit from the new company B on time.

HR from B told me that it's my decision whether I want to stay longer at A while they apply for a work permit. However, they were confident of securing the work permit by the end of my notice period at A and said that they'd prefer that I resigned from A immediately.

Following this, I resigned from A. But another foreigner friend of mine who switches jobs quite frequently in country X strongly advised me against my move when he came to know about it. This got me worried. I not want to resign so early, but I am eager to join company B and HR of B sounded very confident and made the other option sound unattractive by citing numerous delays about pushing back the start date.

**What is a good way to tell HR of my new company that I changed my mind?** I don't expect any problems like termination of the offer or something like that. I'm mainly looking for a good way to tell them I changed my mind, not how to deal with any potential issues that arise from that.

Comment: how long has it been since you sent the email?

Comment: @Jesse one day ago. I don't think this is a workplace issue since it's mainly about finding a good way to formulate what I want to say, not why/if I should push back the date at all and what the consequences would be.

Comment: Don't put it as "You changed your mind", that may look bad on you, put it as "I've had unforeseen difficulties which require me to push back my start date"

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to say "country X"?  Do you think that the COUNTRY you're in is too personally identifying?  Having the country might help with context.

Comment: You say you have already resigned from A and are serving the notice period. There's no real changing your mind now. You can't tell A that you still want to work for them and then resign again once you get a work visa. That will *completely* burn any bridges you have.

Answer (score 1):

**If you've notified company A of your resignation, no point extending that resignation.**  You've made the choice and there's little going back (without potentially upsetting both companies and having no work permit).

If you've not given notice of your resignation at company A, then you could say something to company B like:

**I'm looking forward to coming to work for company B.  After consulting with an immigration adviser, I would like to delay my start date until after the work permit has been secured.  I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but starting before then exposes me to more risk than I am comfortable with, and I want to be able to start my position there without any distractions.  I am still committed to starting at company B, and please let me know if there are any issues with this. 
 I appreciate the team at company B working with me on this matter.**

You should realize, that company B may rescind the offer of employment if you take this second option.  It seems unlikely, and if they do - you may have dodged a bullet by NOT working for them.  But you should be aware of this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to immigration and situations like this the best course of action is to be transparent and mention the issues like you've done here. As you've stated, it's possible that your work permit can get rejected in between you switching jobs which will cause a lot of problems. Make sure that Company B is aware of your reasoning and let them know thats whats holding you back from jumping onboard. It's a very reasonable reason as well.

Another thing to note is how does Company B go about this as that will tell you a lot about the company culture.